# Error when applying group_by/do over a data frame, tibble / assignment

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, assign, tibble

I am applying a function over a grouped data frame using the following procedure, with dplyr:

```
Input2 <- data.frame(ens=rep(as.character(1:51), each=114),
                    dates_UTC= rep(as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2013-01-06 00:00:00"), by="1 hour")), 51),
                    LE = sample(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.002,0.001), 114*51, replace=T),
                    ETPh = rep(0, 114*51),
                    ech = rep(1:114, 51),
                    NiveauResR = rep(c(32.1, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    NiveauResS = rep(c(223, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU1=rep(c(0.028, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU2=rep(c(0, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU3=rep(c(0, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU4=rep(c(0, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU5=rep(c(0, rep(NA, 113)), each=51),
                    HU6=rep(c(0, rep(NA, 113)), each=51))

Qmm_prev <- group_by(Input2, ens) %>%
  dplyr::do(data.frame(dates_prev =.$dates_UTC, Q = test2(.))) %>%
  unnest(cols=c())
```

With (simplified from reality)

```
test2 <- function(x){
  Qmm_prev <- vector(length=nrow(x))
  for (ech in 1:nrow(x))
  {
   if (ech < 114){     
      x[ech, 8:ncol(x)] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
    }
    Qmm_prev[ech] <- 10
  }
  return(Qmm_prev)
}
```

I have the following error :

```
Error: Assigned data `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` must be compatible with row subscript `ech`.
x 1 row must be assigned.
x Assigned data has 6 rows.
i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This code worked a few months ago, and if I replace the group_by/do code by a loop on "ens", it also works. I believe there is something gramatically wrong for the group_by/do, but I can't manage to find it... I know this comes from this line:

```
 x[ech, 8:ncol(x)] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

But since it works when I am testing it with a loop, I don't find the problem and how to correct it...

Does anyone has a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is another variable in my original code, I forgot to replace it into my example. Its value is 114. I edited the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as the error message says :

Change your line from :

```
x[ech, 8:ncol(x)] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

to

```
x[ech, 8:ncol(x)] <- as.list(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

and the code works as expected :

```
Qmm_prev <- group_by(Input2, ens) %>%
  dplyr::do(data.frame(dates_prev =.$dates_UTC, Q = test2(.)))
```

However, note that `do` has been superseded and probably a better way to write `test2` is possible.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! But I still don't really know what happened. I didn't know for "do", I will check that. And indeed for test2, this function was just for the example on stack, but is far more different and complex in reality.